# WM_GETTEXT gets only first character

Tags: visual-c++, windows-xp, wine

So, hello everybody.

I've got MSVC6 installed on win2k on virtual machine, but executable is run under wine emulating winXP (weird eh?).

I have some code, that creates an array of EDIT fields:

```
        for (i=0; i<NDRIVES_MASK+1; i++) {
            hWndEdit_Nstep[i] = CreateWindowEx (NULL,
                "EDIT",
                "0",
                WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_BORDER,
                150, // x
                45+40*i,  // y
                75,  // w
                40,  // h
                hWnd,
                (HMENU)IDC_NSTEP_EDIT[i],
                GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                NULL);
            sprintf(str, "Число полушагов [%3d]", i);
        };
```

And I've got some other code part, that attempts to read data in those EDITs:

```
            for (i=0; i<NDRIVES_MASK+1; i++) {
                DriveN = i;
                printf("--- [DEBUG] - DriveN - %#x\n", DriveN);
                SendMessage(hWndEdit_Nstep[DriveN],
                          WM_GETTEXT,
                          (WPARAM)256,
                          (LPARAM)buftext);
                Nsteps = _wtoi(buftext);
                printf("--- [DEBUG] - Nsteps - %#x\n", Nsteps);
                wprintf(L"--- [DEBUG] - Nsteps - %s\n", buftext);
            }   // for (i, ndrives)
```

UPDATE:

buftext is declared as follows:

```
wchar_t buftext[256];
```

My question is - when I enter only one-digit decimal in any one or even in a couple of those EDITs those numbers a read and output correctly. But when I type in multiple-digit decimals - they're treat as zero.
What this problem is about?

Thanks in advance. Sorry for my broken English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show the declaration of buftext, but I suspect that you typed it as a wide character buffer and used `_wtoi` when you intended to use `atoi`.

Comment: Yeah, buftext i declared as: `wchar_t buftext[256];`. But when I use `atoi` instead of `_wtoi` I get an error of: **'atoi' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned short [256]' to 'const char *'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast.**

Maybe there is a way to retrieve EDIT's text as `char*`?

Comment: Assuming this is not a _UNICODE build, you have to correct your buftext declaration as well: `char buftext[256];`

Comment: thanks alot. Sorry for this 'dumb' question. I have no experience with winapi (as I have no documentation on it).